# socket.io - can't send messages to a spesific room in a socket

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I am trying use socket.io + angular to create a chat room web application.

I have a specific text box in which the user enter the name of the room he wants to connect. then, I am trying to connect this user into that specific room and send all of his messages to this room.

however, when I am trying to send a string into the chat, the request is being handle on the server side (the console log output is printed from the server) but not on the controller socket.on('chat_message', function(data) ...) method does not print it console log.

what am I doing wrong?

the code is below. there is more code that I don't think is required (angular related stuff).

Thanks in advance

view

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
  <input autocomplete="off" ng-model="insertedText" type="text" />
  <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">
    Send
  </button>
</form>
```

controller

```
mymodule.controller("cntrlChat", ['$scope', 'myService',
  function($scope, myService){ 
   var socket = io();
   $scope.messages = [];
   $scope.room= myService.get();
   socket.emit('room', $scope.room);

   $scope.submit=function(){
    socket.emit('chat_message',{ room: $scope.room, msg: $scope.user+": "+$scope.insertedText });
    $scope.insertedText='';
    return false; 
  }

  socket.on('chat_message', function(data){
    console.log('room-->'+data.room+' msg---->'+data.msg );
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.messages.push(data.msg);

    });
  });

}]);
```

server

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app); 
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
io.emit('chat_message', "welcome");

socket.on('room', function(room) {
    socket.join(room);
});

socket.on('chat_message', function(data){
    console.log("room---->"+data.room, "msg---->"+data.msg);
    io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('chat message',data.msg);
});


socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    io.emit('chat message', "Bye");

});

});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: You're going to need a lot more details than "it doesn't work" if you want some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are emitting `chat message` from the server and waiting for `chat_message` on  the client. Look carefully, one has an underscore the other a space.

It might just be a typo error.

Avoid spaces and special characters in message labels.

Answer (score 1):

the error is here
   io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('chat message',data.msg);

it should be 
    io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('chat_message',data.msg);

Comment: so instead of :
io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('chat_message',data.msg);
what should I write?

Comment: you didnot write chat_message you wrote chat(space)message